# Inequality of Lp-norm with supremum

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces, approximation

I'm reading a paper about the universal approximation of radial basis function (RBF) networks [1].

I cannot obtain the first inequality of Lemma 1 (right after "with $q$ defined by ..."), as shown in the below picture.
Is there anyone who can derive this inequality?

Thanks.

[image]

[1] J. Park and I. W. Sandberg, “Universal Approximation Using Radial-Basis-Function Networks,” Neural Computation, vol. 3, no. 2, pp. 246–257, Jun. 1991, doi: 10.1162/neco.1991.3.2.246.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472394/lp-norm-representation-via-duality This is called the dual characterization of the $L^p$ norm.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks a lot! Then, why is it represented as an inequality instead of an equality?